# Show that a set S is a closed subset of C([0,1])

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

S = $\{\frac{sin(nx)}{1 + n} \ s.t. \ n \in N, x \in [0,1]\}$

Show that S is a closed subset of C([0,1])

My instructor told me there was a "way of thinking of this," and that if you don't see it right away, you won't be able to get the solution. I must be not thinking of it correctly as I am not quite sure how to go about it. Does anyone have a way of getting started that could help guide me?

At the time I do not have a solution attempt. I really am not even convinced this is continuous right now since Sin(nx) could be -1, which is outside of [0,1]. So I'm not even convinced this is continuous at the moment.

Thank you!

Comment: $\sin(nx)$ could be anything, the important thing is that $x$ **is in** $[0,1]$.

Comment: Which topology are you taking into account on $C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos maybe you can clarify something for me. My professor has not really talked about "this topology vs that topology" for say. He just gives us questions and tell us to do them. He talks about any topology in a general sense, just like he did metric spaces. So I'm actually not sure.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It seems the topology of uniform convergence.

Comment: If you don't know which topology you are working with, then what does “closed subset” mean to you?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos a set that includes its boundary and is fully contained in the larger set. That's how I would think of it.

Comment: Just a question $0\in\Bbb N$ for you?

Comment: Then what is the boundary of a set?

Comment: @TitoEliatron no, to me N is the positive counting numbers. That is how my instructor does it as well.

Comment: @DominicBlanco If so, I don't think your set is closed. And here you have a HINT.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos a set of points on the edge for say. Like they're at the end of the closed interval.

Comment: Then what does edge mean?

Comment: @TitoEliatron I was told the set is closed. Hmm, do you think it could be a typo?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos edge means boundary to me. To me they are synonyms here. Like I can't really get more general unless if I pull out a dictionary.

Comment: @DominicBlanco If $0\in N$ it is closed, if $0\notin N$, then it is not closed.

Comment: So, for you “edge” means “boundary” and “boundary” means “edge”? Don't you see a problem there?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos not really. That's just definition to me. I was trying to think of words to answer your question, and I don't think I can get any more simple than those words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On any metric space, if $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a convergent sequence, if $x$ is its limit, and if $x\ne x_n$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$, then the set $\{x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is not a closed set.

So, *if* you are working with the distance $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$, then, since$$\left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{1+n}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$$converges to the null function, and since none of the functions $x\mapsto\frac{\sin(nx)}{1+n}$ is the null function, the set $S$ is actually *not* a closed set.

Comment: If you assume that $0\in\Bbb N$ (or you let your sequence begin at $n=0$), then Yes, it is closed. It is a ver funny situation.

Comment: @TitoEliatron it may have been a typo by my teacher. N has never included 0 in our class. I'll have to ask him about it. That would explain a lot.

Comment: The $n+1$ in denominator let me think that in this case $n=0$ is included in the sequence.

Comment: It does make sense though, I can see the problem now. Not including 0 becomes a big issue.